# Windows Authentication in Bonobo GIT

Tags: windows-authentication, bonobo

I want to enable Windows Authentication for Bonobo Git (version 6.3). I modified the `web.config` and enabled Windows Authentication as shown below. Post that, I created Windows User (e.g. - xyz) on the server (where Bonobo Git is installed) and also in Bonobo Git application. When I login with user 'xyz', then it is not getting authenticated and the error it says "`Failed to find user xyz`"

```xml
 <add key="AuthenticationProvider" value="Windows" />
 <add key="ImportWindowsAuthUsersAsAdmin" value="false" />
 <add key="MembershipService" value="Internal" />
```